# React-native: How to Show the tooltip with out clicking on marker in react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am using react-native-maps module.I have given lat and long values and i have used MapView.Marker to show the Marker and tooltip when clicking on the marker.

But, Now I want to show the tooltip with out clicking on the marker when the map loads initially.

this is my code here:

```
<View style={styles.page}>
        <MapView
          ref="map"
          style={styles.map}
          region={this.state.region}
          provider = {PROVIDER_DEFAULT}
          zoomEnabled={true}
          onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange.bind(this)}
          pitchEnabled={true}
          showsCompass={true}
          liteMode={false}
          showsBuildings={true}
          showsTraffic={true}
          showsIndoors={true}
        >
        <MapView.Marker
      coordinate={this.state.marker.latlng}
      title={this.state.marker.title}
      description={this.state.marker.description}
      image={require('./assets/pin.png')}

    />

        </MapView>
      </View>
```

Can any one help how to solve this...

Answer (score 12):

I couldn't find any documentation on any sort of onLoad prop for MapView so I used onLayout instead as [suggested here](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/367). You will need to use the [showCallout method](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/marker.md#methods) for the Marker to show the tooltip. To do this, add a ref for the marker that you can then use in onLayout for the MapView.

```
<View style={styles.page}>
    <MapView
        ref="map"
        style={styles.map}
        region={this.state.region}
        provider = {PROVIDER_DEFAULT}
        zoomEnabled={true}
        onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange.bind(this)}
        pitchEnabled={true}
        showsCompass={true}
        liteMode={false}
        showsBuildings={true}
        showsTraffic={true}
        showsIndoors={true}
        onLayout={() => { this.mark.showCallout(); }}
    >
        <MapView.Marker
            ref={ref => { this.mark = ref; }}
            coordinate={this.state.marker.latlng}
            title={this.state.marker.title}
            description={this.state.marker.description}
            image={require('./assets/pin.png')}
        />
    </MapView>
</View>
```

Comment: Hello , Thanks for your response , i am using as you are modified code but i have a small error. how can i  write onLayout() function can you give me  suggest

Comment: @Lavaraju What's the error you are getting? The example code should work as is since I tested it before posting.

Comment: The Error was can't find layout() function

Comment: @Lavaraju Do you mean onLayout? The method should be onLayout (case sensitive), not layout.

Comment: Yah But i didn'tt get

Comment: @Lavaraju Can you show me what your MapView and MapView.Marker code looks like? Or show me the **exact** error you are getting? You can post it online at a place like pastebin. It's the only way I'll be able to understand what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @MichaelCheng `onLayout` seems to be called too early. It doesn't show the callout, at least not on iOS. As a workaround I use `onRegionChangeComplete` but it is a bit buggy (again, on iOS).

Answer (score 0):

Well what worked for me was using ref on that particular marker

const originMarker = useRef(null);

and then on component mount: originMarker?.current?.showCallout();